# Use command line variable in later code

Tags: c#, variables, adodb

I have a WinForm,

I am have added command line functions as so-

```
foreach (string arg in args)
        {

            if (arg == "-id")
            {
                string u = "";

                ADODB.Connection ADconn = new ADODB.Connection();
                string connstr = "db connection string";

                ADconn.ConnectionString = connstr;

                object recs;

                ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();

                ADconn.Open(connstr);

                string qry = string.Format("Select ID from TABLE where NO = '" + args[counts + 1] + "'");

                rs = ADconn.Execute(qry, out recs, 0);

                for (; !rs.EOF; rs.MoveNext())
                {
                    string test = rs.Fields["column"].Value.ToString();

                    u = test;

                }

            }

            counts = counts + 1;
        }
```

Therefore `args[counts + 1]` is whatever variable the user input in the command line after `-id`. I need to use this value later on in my code however how can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "later"?  Down further in the same method?  In another method of the same class?  In another class?  In another project in the same solution?

Comment: You should save `args[counts + 1]` value in the variable or the field. Should not you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a class with static properties that encapsulate the command line arguments, e.g.

```
public class RunConfiguration
{
    public static int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Initialize the values in your *main()* routine.  You can then reference them anywhere in your program like

```
int id = RunConfiguration.Id;
```

Comment: This is already done for you automatically (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx)

Comment: Sure you can get them anywhere, but my philosophy is to process them when you get them.  Store the meaning that they have for your program, not the raw command line arguments.  Otherwise, you may end up duplicating the command line parsing code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) to access command line arguments from anywhere in your program, not just the main method.  (It prevents you from needing to pass them around everywhere as well.)

Comment: Why reprocess them elsewhere?  Process them when you get them and store the result...

Comment: @EricJ. I assumed he just wanted to move this existing code snippet to somewhere other than the `main` method, not to do it in both places.

Comment: anyway he needs to save somewhere index value (`counts + 1`). so what difference between saving `counts + 1` and `args[counts + 1]`? or you mean that he has to process all agruments once again???!!!

Comment: @ie. Well, I would suggest just not computing the data until right before you need it, rather than computing it first thing and saving it for later, unless you're sure that you're going to be needing to use it repeatedly in a lot of places.

Comment: @Servy well, it is not really clear from the question, but I guess the using of the `args[counts + 1]` in the code from question is not an issue Jambo has faced with